# How to distribute sales with partitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables:

1st table columns: ItemCode int, Amount float (I have over 1000 ItemCodes)
2nd table columns: ItemCode int, SoldAmount float, Price float (I have over 10000 sale rows for different items)

Example:

ItemId 1528's Amount in 1st table is 244. That items sales in the 2nd table is as below:

```
Sale 1 Amount = 120, Price = 10
Sale 2 Amount = 120, Price = 30
Sale 3 Amount = 100, Price = 20
Sale 4 Amount = 10,  Price = 25
```

| ItemCode | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1528 | 244 |
| 1530 | 150 |

| ItemCode | Date | Amount | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1528 | 2021.11.01 | 120 | 10 |
| 1530 | 2021.10.01 | 120 | 30 |
| 1528 | 2021.09.01 | 100 | 20 |
| 1530 | 2021.08.01 | 10 | 25 |

Tried cursor and loop , but no desired output.

The desired outcome is to distribute that 100 amount with the sales above like following:
Sale 1 Amount 60: 100 - 60 = 40 with price 5 --- So we continue to the next row and subtract whatever is left
Sale 2 Amount 30: 40 - 30 = 10 with price 6 --- So we continue to the next row and subtract whatever is left
Sale 3 Amount 20: 10 - 20 = -10 with price 7 --- So we stop here as the amount is equal to 0 or below .

As the result we should get this:

```
60 * 5 = 300
30 * 6 = 180
10 * 7 = 70    (that 10 is derived from whatever could be subtracted before it hits 0)
```

Desired table as below

| ItemCode | Date | Amount | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1528 | 2021.11.01 | 120 | 10 |
| 1528 | 2021.10.01 | 120 | 30 |
| 1528 | 2021.09.01 | 4 | 20 |

My last attempt was as below

```
WITH CTE AS (

SELECT ItemCode, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM table 1
GROUP BY STOCKREF )

SELECT *,
IIF(LAG(table1.Amount - table2.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY table1.Amount ORDER BY Date DESC) IS NULL, table1.Amount - table2.amount,
LAG(table1.Amount - table2.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.ItemCode ORDER BY Date DESC) - table2.AMOUNT) AS COL

FROM CTE JOIN (SELECT ItemCode, DATE_, AMOUNT, PRICE FROM table2) table 2 ON table1.ItemCode = table2.Amount
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with actual sample data, desired results, and your actual attempt.

Comment: The 1st table:
ItemCode, Amount
2,0
6,0
1311,720
1312,6660
1313,2558
1314,5550
1315,4240
1316,6500

--------------

Second table: 
ItemCode, Date, SoldAmount, Price
1528,2021-11-29,120,6.76292
1528,2021-11-15,120,6.6453
1528,2021-11-01,100,6.96875
1528,2021-10-18,120,6.10725
1528,2021-10-04,125,6.10725
1528,2021-09-20,100,6.36439

Comment: thanks for reply, but cannot paste the table properly. if needed i can link a screenshot or something else

Comment: LINK: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1myP8tfKXSh90Ftm88mM9BRGd5uGAlQQ6yOLX1dtIvOY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry for that, but could not post the data as table

Comment: thanks, just edited

Comment: thanks @lptr . worked well .

Comment: .…..    .….. 

Comment: @lptr any reason not to post as an answer?

Comment: @DaleK.. maybe someone posts a different approach/answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this addresses the right question - if you're trying to create a running total per item_code, deducting the sale quantity from starting inventory from first-to-last sale, maybe this would work:

```
CREATE TABLE #items (item_code   INT,
                     item_amount INT);
                    
 INSERT INTO #items (item_code, item_amount)
      VALUES        (1528,      244);
      
 INSERT INTO #items (item_code, item_amount)
       VALUES       (1529,      240);      
  
CREATE TABLE #sales (item_code   INT,
                     sale_date   DATE,
                     sale_amount INT,
                     sale_price  DECIMAL(12,2));
                    
INSERT INTO #sales (item_code, sale_date,    sale_amount, sale_price)
     VALUES        (1528,      '2021-12-01', 50,          5); 
                    
INSERT INTO #sales (item_code, sale_date,    sale_amount, sale_price)
     VALUES        (1528,      '2021-11-29', 120,         6.76292);
      
INSERT INTO #sales (item_code, sale_date,    sale_amount, sale_price)
     VALUES        (1528,      '2021-11-15', 120,         6.6453);        

INSERT INTO #sales (item_code, sale_date,    sale_amount, sale_price)
     VALUES        (1528,      '2021-11-01', 100,         6.96875);        
     
INSERT INTO #sales (item_code, sale_date,    sale_amount, sale_price)
     VALUES        (1529,      '2021-11-30', 48,         7.2);    

INSERT INTO #sales (item_code, sale_date,    sale_amount, sale_price)
     VALUES        (1529,      '2021-11-18', 48,         3.5);         

INSERT INTO #sales (item_code, sale_date,    sale_amount, sale_price)
     VALUES        (1529,      '2021-11-09', 96,         3.9);              

INSERT INTO #sales (item_code, sale_date,    sale_amount, sale_price)
     VALUES        (1529,      '2021-11-05', 96,         3.75); 
      
;WITH all_sales_with_running_totals AS (  --Calculate the running total of each item, deducting sale amount from total starting amount, in order of first sale to last
    SELECT s.item_code,
           s.sale_date,
           s.sale_price,
           i.item_amount AS starting_amount,
           s.sale_amount,
           i.item_amount - SUM(sale_amount) OVER(PARTITION BY s.item_code
                                                     ORDER BY s.sale_date
                                                         ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                            ) AS running_sale_amount
    FROM #sales AS s
    JOIN #items AS i ON s.item_code = i.item_code
),
sales_with_prev_running_total AS (  --Add the previous rows' running total, to assist with the final calculation
    SELECT item_code,
           sale_date,
           sale_price,
           starting_amount,
           sale_amount,
           running_sale_amount,
           LAG(running_sale_amount, 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY item_code
                                                      ORDER BY sale_date
                                             )AS prev_running_sale_amount
      FROM all_sales_with_running_totals
)
SELECT item_code, --Return the final running sale amount for each sale - if the inventory has already run out, return null.  If there is insufficient inventory to fill the order, fill it with the qty remaining.  Otherwise, fill the entire order.
       sale_date,
       sale_price,
       starting_amount,
       sale_amount,
       running_sale_amount,
       prev_running_sale_amount,
       CASE WHEN prev_running_sale_amount <= 0
            THEN NULL
            WHEN running_sale_amount < 0
            THEN prev_running_sale_amount
            ELSE sale_amount
             END AS result_sale_amount
  FROM sales_with_prev_running_total;
```